# Python Data Transformation

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with two columns

[image: Original Dataset]

How to convert into the format given below using **Python**?

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and [put your input and output in the question itself, as plain text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551), [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please include data&code as text and not images and show your attempt (see also: [ask]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` on `Name`, `aggregate` `Sr Number` as lists then `apply` `pd.Series` on it to create rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sr Number':np.arange(1,12),'Name':['A']*3+['B']*2+['C']*4+['D']*2}).groupby('Name')['Sr Number'].agg(list).reset_index()
df['Instance'] = df.index + 1
df[[f'Row ID {i}' for i in range(1,len(df)+1)]] = df['Sr Number'].apply(pd.Series)
df = df[['Instance','Name','Row ID 1','Row ID 2','Row ID 3','Row ID 4']].replace(np.nan, '')
```

Output:

```
   Instance Name  Row ID 1  Row ID 2 Row ID 3 Row ID 4
0         1    A       1.0       2.0      3.0         
1         2    B       4.0       5.0                  
2         3    C       6.0       7.0      8.0      9.0
3         4    D      10.0      11.0
```